# Patching a contract with deprecated instructions

Tags: smart-contracts

The following contract (Hic Et Nunc Marketplace V1) contains the deprecated instruction `SUB` on type `mutez`:

https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/objkt-swap/blob/master/michelson/objkt_swap_v1.tz

I want to deploy this contract out of curiosity.

How do I patch it properly so that I can deploy the contract to e.g. Ghostnet? Although I attempted replacing the deprecated instructions with `SUB_MUTEZ`, I still haven't been able to deploy the contract. This boils down to me not fully understanding which `SUB` instructions are the ones that need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

[SUB_MUTEZ](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-SUB_MUTEZ) is resulting in OPTION MUTEZ, which has to be consumed.

Thus, you have to replace the corresponding SUB with:

```
SUB_MUTEZ;
IF_NONE { FAIL } {};
```

For your specific contract you have to replace the [SUB at line 821](https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/objkt-swap/blob/master/michelson/objkt_swap_v1.tz#L821), since this is the instruction which tries to subtract MUTEZ values.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, yet after replacing said instruction, I'm confronted with another error:

```
At line 496 characters 26 to 41,
  wrong stack type for instruction TRANSFER_TOKENS: []
```

Checking further via:
```
octez-client typecheck script test.tz -v

At line 4583 characters 26 to 41,
  wrong stack type for instruction TRANSFER_TOKENS: [].
Fatal error:
  ill-typed script
```

Comment: It works for me and the above linked contract. Sry, cant' help. Or you have to post more information (your changed contract, versions, etc.).

Comment: At first attempt I didn't realize that I need to replace the corresponding instruction with both lines you posted, which I now did. Cheers!

Followup question, how can I (automatically, like in a script) detect which SUB instructions must be replaced?

Comment: Can't see a nice solution for this. However, you could try:

1) Run octez-client with flag -v (like you already did).

2) Identify the place where there are no more any comments for the instructions.

3) Replace the SUB with the replacement code.


Redo the steps above.